# InvalidLocationConstraint error while creating S3 bucket when the used command is

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

An error occurred (InvalidLocationConstraint) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The specified location-constraint is not valid when using the command

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket my-bucket
--create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=region
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the command you used.

Comment: Please include a question in your statement ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Used this command. Remove the location constraint and it worked

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket mytest-bucket
```

Answer (score 33):

If your region is us-east-1 then you simply run the command without the --location constraint because by default bucket is created in the us-east-1 region

Comment: Does this choice of behavior make any sense to anyone?  Why should it matter if your constraint happens to be the default case?  Even if there's a reason for this, AWS should fix it in the client code to make this a non issue.  This behavior...needing to special case your code for one particular region...makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: It sure does not, this is frustrating wasting time on this

Comment: Indeed, AWS throws an error when trying to set LocationConstraint to us-east-1. It's definitely a bug on AWS side and they need to fix it

Comment: `aws-cli/2.13.0` and the problem still existing.

Answer (score 6):

try this u will get now    aws s3 mb s3://bucket-name --region us-east-1

Answer (score 1):

aws s3 mb s3://greengrass-component-artifacts-123456789-region --region us-east-1

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when specifying the profile, this error fell, but if you enter the desired zone along with the profile, then the bucket was created:

```
aws s3 mb s3://mynewsuperuniquebucket --profile neededProfile --region us-east-1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue arose from a disabled region:

```
$ aws s3api create-bucket --bucket "$bucket_name" --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=ap-southeast-3

An error occurred (InvalidLocationConstraint) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The specified location-constraint is not valid
```

Vefiry if a region is enabled at https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/account or via AWS CLI:

```
$ aws account get-region-opt-status --region-name ap-southeast-3 --output json
{
    "RegionName": "ap-southeast-3",
    "RegionOptStatus": "DISABLED"
}
```

To enable the region, follow this command:

```
$ aws account enable-region --region-name ap-southeast-3
$ aws account get-region-opt-status --region-name ap-southeast-3 --output json
{
    "RegionName": "ap-southeast-3",
    "RegionOptStatus": "ENABLING"
}
```

Wait until it's enabled (did not find a `wait` command akin to `aws ec2 wait`):

```
while [[ "$(aws account get-region-opt-status --region-name ap-southeast-3 --output json | jq -r .RegionOptStatus)" == "ENABLING" ]]; do sleep 1; done
```

This process took approximately 10 minutes for me.

I also had to incorporate the `--region` option during bucket creation (otherwise I was still getting `An error occurred (InvalidLocationConstraint) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The specified location-constraint is not valid`), I'm guessing it was because the enabled region was not propagated yet to the region where the `PUT` API call was going to.

```
$ aws s3api create-bucket --bucket "$bucket_name" --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=ap-southeast-3 --output json --region ap-southeast-3
```